# Show average execution time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in sql which looks like below:

```
ID          JOB_NAME                START_DATE_TIME         END_DATE_TIME

748425  HOURLY_PLAZA_MISSING    2013-10-30 13:15:01.040 2013-10-30 13:15:14.420
748424  HOURLY_AUTOREPL         2013-10-30 13:05:00.950 2013-10-30 13:05:02.390
748423  HOURLY_LANE             2013-10-30 13:00:01.500 2013-10-30 13:00:10.080
748422  HOURLY_EMAIL            2013-10-30 13:00:01.460 2013-10-30 13:02:00.650
748421  HOURLY_EASYPAY          2013-10-30 13:00:01.410 2013-10-30 13:00:04.820
748420  HOURLY_PROCESS          2013-10-30 13:00:01.290 2013-10-30 13:25:11.450
748419  HOURLY_COPY_SUSPENSE    2013-10-30 13:00:01.240 2013-10-30 13:03:39.660
748418  HOURLY_I95              2013-10-30 13:00:01.230 2013-10-30 13:19:46.170
748414  HOURLY_PLAZA_MISSING    2013-10-30 12:15:01.020 2013-10-30 12:15:04.070
748413  HOURLY_PROCESS          2013-10-30 12:06:30.480 2013-10-30 12:31:41.610
748411  HOURLY_AUTOREPL         2013-10-30 12:05:01.070 2013-10-30 12:05:02.440
748409  HOURLY_I95              2013-10-30 12:00:01.430 2013-10-30 12:45:48.060
748408  HOURLY_EMAIL            2013-10-30 12:00:01.420 2013-10-30 12:02:14.620
748406  HOURLY_EASYPAY          2013-10-30 12:00:01.330 2013-10-30 12:00:04.640
```

If you notice carefully, the jobs are repeating every hour HOURLY_PROCESS happened on 2013-10-30 12:06:30.480 and 2013-10-30 13:00:01.290

I need a sql query which will show the output like blow:

```
JOB_NAME                Average_Time of Execution
HOURLY_PROCESS         (END_DATE_TIME-START_DATE_TIME)/Last 10 occurances of HOURLY_PROCESS
```

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way, if you are content to have the differences shown in seconds.

```
select job_name, (sum(diff_ms/1000.0) / count(*)) as avg_seconds
from (select t.*,
             datediff(ms, start_date_time, end_datetime) as diff_ms
             row_number() over (partition by job_name order by start_date_time desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 10
group by job_name;
```

Comment: i tried the same  select job_name, (sum(diff_ms/1000.0) / count(*)) as avg_seconds
from (select esp_generic_application.job_name,
             datediff(ms, esp_generic_application.start_date_time, esp_generic_application.end_datetime) as diff_ms
             row_number() over (partition by esp_generic_application.job_name order by esp_generic_application.start_date_time desc) as seqnum
      from esp_generic_application
     ) esp_generic_application
where rownum <= 10
group by job_name;     but it says incorrect syntax. i am using sql server 2005.
Incorrect syntax near 'row_number'.

Comment: i missed a comma before row_number() so i tried the corrected one and i got.....    select job_name, (sum(diff_ms/1000.0) / count(*)) as avg_seconds
from (select esp_generic_job.job_name,
             datediff(ms, esp_generic_job.start_date_time, esp_generic_job.end_date_time) as diff_ms,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by esp_generic_job.job_name order by esp_generic_job.start_date_time desc) as seqnum
      from esp_generic_job
     ) esp_generic_job
where rownum <= 10
group by job_name; But it shows: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'rownum'

Comment: You don't have a column aliased or named rownum.  Perhaps you  meant seqnum?

Comment: @Andrew . . . Alas, yes.  Fixed.